# Where to find this control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for this control.

[image: this control].

I can't find it in the VB.NET toolbox. Can you tell me it's name?

Comment: Whoever voted down this post could atleast have the courtesy to explain *why* they found this inappropriate. I see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @inquisitive see my edit. OP posted the screenshot to an external site, I inlined it.

Comment: @StephanB, you really did a great job in upgrading the quality and expression of the post. new users do not have rights to inline screenshots. As a peer reviewer, it was your goodwill to do so. But it did not warrant a -1 penalty. That too on a noob.

Comment: @inquisitive Sorry for my short comment, I see now it was ambigious. I edited the question and posted my answer after it was downvoted by someone else. Downvoting, editing and answering would be pretty rude, I agree :D In my first comment I simply wanted to point to the first version of the question to explain why someone found it inappropriate.

Comment: @StephanB, sorry for the misunderstanding. user2803984, good luck on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it is a [BindingNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingnavigator.aspx), it selects the active record of a `DataBinding` used on a `DataSet`.